# Merge [context-api] into [react-context]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

The tag name "[context-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-api)" is pretty ambiguous when considered amongst a sea of other tags on Stack Overflow. In reality, **all** uses seem to refer to React's `Context` API. The [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) does not call this feature "Context API" — it's just "Context".

There are ~500 questions tagged with [context-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-api). [Filtering out [reactjs], [react-native], [react-hooks], and [react-router-dom]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-api+-reactjs+-react-native+-react-hooks+-react-router-dom) leaves only 6 questions, all of which are still React questions.

So I propose that we should **merge [context-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-api) into the existing [react-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-context) tag**, which has >1200 questions. Unfortunately I don't have enough rep in the tags to propose a synonym, but hopefully someone else can do that. Still, I think merging is preferable so that we can be rid of the old [context-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/context-api) tag.

Comment: Both excerpts are about the React Context API: "_React Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level._" and "_Context-API is a global state management system for React through the use of the React hook useContext()._". Also, searching for "context api" on Google only shows React results for me. I agree that the tags should be merged.

Comment: Agreed. Synonym proposed.